# Django filter error sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1

Tags: python, django

I would like to suggest same post categories on the current page detail
So I try the following code:

My views :

```
def recipe(request, slug, message=''):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    post_category = post.category.all() # get the categories of the post
    posts_same_category = Post.objects.filter(
        Q(category__name__icontains= post_category) # filter the same categories of the other posts
        ).filter(published=True).exclude(slug=slug) # exclude the current post and no publish posts
```

My models :

```
class PostCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField('PostCategory', blank=True)
    mealtype = models.ManyToManyField('MealType', blank=True)
```

I have a error on the post detail page :

```
sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1
```

I think the problem is with the ManytoManyField but what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing **objects** in comparison to **CharField**.

Here,

```
category__name__icontains= post_category
#category__name ---> CharField
#post_category ---> Query set [<PostCategory obj>....]
```

try something which fetch you **only name** or change query accordingly:

```
posts_same_category = Post.objects.filter(category__in=post.category.all(), published=True).exclude(slug=slug)
```

additionally, you can have a look at [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Comment: thanks for your help @DARK_COD3R this solution return an empty queryset whereas i have 3 similar category in the database : copy of my shell :                                                        posts = Post.objects.all() >>> post = posts[5]
>>> print(post)
Profiteroles
>>> post_category=post.category.all()
>>> print(post_category)
<QuerySet [<PostCategory: recettes sucrées>] >>> posts_same_category = Post.objects.filter(Q(category__name__icontains=[p.name for p in  post_category]))
>>> print(posts_same_category)
<QuerySet []>   Do you know why ?