# django.db.utils.OperationalError: sub-select returns 8 columns - expected 1

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm attempting to generate a QuerySet that collects all the tags that are posted in all of a given user's posted questions. On top of that, annotate over each Tag instance to find out how many times each tag was posted.

The problem I'm encountering however is with the following error that is being raised:

- `django.db.utils.OperationalError: sub-select returns 8 columns - expected 1`

What is this error referring to and how can it be resolved in order to get the aforementioned desired QuerySet?

```
class TestProfileInstanceTagData(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user("ItsMe")
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user=cls.user)

        tag1 = Tag.objects.create(name="TagA")
        tag2 = Tag.objects.create(name="TagB")
        tag3 = Tag.objects.create(name="TagZ")

        question1 = Question.objects.create(
            title="This is a title about question1",
            body="This is the post content about question1",
            profile=profile
        )
        question1.tags.add(tag3)

        question2 = Question.objects.create(
            title="This is a title about question2",
            body="This is the post content about question2",
            profile=profile
        )
        question2.tags.add(*[tag1, tag3])

        question3 = Question.objects.create(
            title="This is a title about question3",
            body="This is the post content about question3",
            profile=profile
        )
        question3.tags.add(tag2)

        cls.queryset = profile.get_tag_post_data()

    def test_user_posted_tag_queryset(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.queryset.count(), 3)
```

```
class Profile(Model):
    user = OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE)

    def get_tag_post_data(self):
        questions_with_tag = self.questions.filter(tags__name=OuterRef("name"))
        return Tag.objects.filter(
            question__profile=self
        ).distinct().annotate(count=Count(Subquery(questions_with_tag)))
```

```
class Tag(Model):

    name = CharField(unique=True, max_length=25)


class Post(Model):

    body = TextField()
    date = DateField(default=date.today)
    comment = ForeignKey('Comment', on_delete=CASCADE, null=True)
    profile = ForeignKey(
        'authors.Profile', on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True,
        related_name='%(class)ss',
        related_query_name="%(class)s"
    )
    vote = GenericRelation(
        'Vote', related_query_name="%(class)s"
    )
    score = IntegerField(default=0)


class Question(Post):

    title = CharField(
        max_length=80, unique_for_date="date",
        help_text="Concisely state the problem you're having",
        error_messages={
            "max_length": "The title of your question is too long"
        }
    )
    tags = ManyToManyField(
        'Tag', related_name="questions", related_query_name="question"
    )
    views = IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60955063/django-filter-error-sub-select-returns-2-columns-expected-1

Comment: That does nothing to help the error I'm getting.

Comment: Can you please post the whole stack trace